# File Storage (S3) with AdonisJS 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-s3, adonis.js

In AdonisJS v4 docs we have [this](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/file-system) section explaining how to stream files to a S3 bucket. I was looking for something similar in AdonisJS v5 docs but it have just an [example](https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/http/file-uploads) of how to upload files to local server.

If it is not ready yet since Adonis 5 is not in it's last version, which is the other way to upload files to S3 though Adonis v5 (specially with typescript)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way to do this with aws-sdk, this code is not 100% mine:

`uploadToS3Bucket` function:

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";


const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
});

export const uploadToS3Bucket = async (
  file: any,
  bucket: string
): Promise<{ key: string; url: string }> => {
  try {
    const { type, subtype, extname } = file;
    let mimeType = type + "/" + subtype;

    let fileType = "image/jpg";

    const name = uuid() + "." + extname;

    let buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(file), "utf-8");

    await s3
      .putObject({
        Key: name,
        Bucket: bucket,
        ContentType: fileType,
        Body: buffer.toString("base64"),
        ACL: "public-read",
      })
      .promise();

    let url = `https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${name}`;
    console.log(url);
    return {
      key: name,
      url,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }
};
```

And in the controller:

```
public async store({ request }: HttpContextContract) {
  let file = getFileFromRequest(request, "defined_file_prop_name_here");

  if (file) {
    await uploadToS3Bucket(file, BUCKET_NAME);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adonis 4 used [flydrive](https://github.com/Slynova-Org/flydrive) to implement s3 storage, which you could also use to simplify and save time. Once configured and instantiated using flydrive is pretty simple

```
// Supported drivers: "local", "s3", "gcs"
await storage.disk('s3').put('testfile.txt', 'filecontents');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it **without** **ACL Permission Issue**

Don't forget **install S3 drive**: https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/drive

Example for multiple images:

```
import Route from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route'
import Drive from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Drive'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { string } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Helpers'

Route.post('upload', async ({ request }) => {

   const images = request.files('images')
   for (let image of images) {
      if (image !== null) {
         const slugFileName = string.camelCase(path.parse(image.clientName).name).toLowerCase();

         const fileName = `${slugFileName}.${image.extname}`
         const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(image.tmpPath!)

         await Drive.putStream(fileName, fileStream, {
            contentType: image.headers['content-type']
         })
      }
   }
})
```

If you want to upload a single image:

```
Route.post('upload', async ({ request }) => {

   const image = request.file('image')
      if (image !== null) {
         const slugFileName = string.camelCase(path.parse(image.clientName).name).toLowerCase();

         const fileName = `${slugFileName}.${image.extname}`
         const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(image.tmpPath!)

         await Drive.putStream(fileName, fileStream, {
            contentType: image.headers['content-type']
         })
      }
})
```